# Multi-client Mobile/Web Application with Data Sync Capabilities - Best DB Platform Options?

Tags: database, mobile, synchronization, real-time, offline

I'd like to understand more about what DB products/combos-of/platforms are generally used these days to build applications which have both mobile and web clients connected to a centralised DB. Lets just say, for example, I wanted to build a simple "To-do" List app which multiple users can download/use. With the following requirements:

- Preferably built using free/open source/community products (understand hosting costs involved) but also happy to hear cloud-based options too (other than Firebase)
- Must support both a mobile (ios/android) & web client (web app)
- Central server-side DB (to support above) with sync capabilities to update clients (mobile/web), when an update takes place clients sync/update
- Offline "read" capability (no offline write necessary)
- NoSQL/Doc DB is fine (RDBMS would work too though)

This exercise is to help me (and others interested) understand the options/products/platforms available when attempting to create an application with such requirements. Its intrigued me for a while what options are available for a non-enterprise, non-commercial application such as a to-do list where a users data is sync'd across devices yet available to a web client too, via an architecture that doesn't come with enterprise costs.

I've looked at various offerings from the main vendors but when it comes to synchronising data between devices and a central server DB, generally paid-for products are required. I see free apps daily which must use highly cost-effective (bordering free) components (above basic hosting) in their architectures and just wonder what products they generally use to achieve apps capable of synchronising data between clients from a centralised DB/server.